# Receiving Imported XML content cannot be parsed Error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to import the pricing from a link. I have tried to use the formula =IMPORTXML and my formula currently looks like this:

=IMPORTXML("https://www.jurassicbark-online.co.uk/products/copy-of-fish4cats-finest-adult-salmon-short-shelf-life-30-6-23?variant=45156699144472", "//div[@class=""single_product__price"")")

However, I am receiving this error.

Please can someone guide me in the right direction, so that the cell shows the items price, which should be £9.99?

Thank you in advance!

I have tried to answer this above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=importxml(A1,"//p[1]/span[1]/span[1]")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Are you able to advise how I can do this for items that have multiple variants? For instance: https://www.jurassicbark-online.co.uk/collections/acana-dry-dog-food/products/acana-adult?variant=14087536050240

What would the formula be for each variant (2, 6, 11.4kg? Really appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Yeah it's only showing the price of 2kg for all weight variants!! Please post a new question specifying this exact use-case & hopefully someone will pitch in with a solution to address this...